# Help calculating a relativistic correction

Tags: special-relativity

There is a turtle in a decelerating spaceship approaching you. His (her?) velocity is

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -kx.$$

Normally we would would integrate and the result would be
$$x=e^{-kt}$$

But what if the spaceship's initial velocity is near to the speed of light? We need to make a relativistic correction as we observe the turtle Everything in the spaceship we observe seems to be going very slowly due to time dilation. The turtle's motions appear glacial, even more slow than we are used to seeing. The turtle of course has no sense of this and is lumbering around the spaceship at his usual slow pace.
Would we say

$$   dt'=((\frac{1}{1-(v/c)^2})^{.5})dt$$
and then integrate

1. $$\frac{dx}{\Biggl((\frac{1}{1-(v/c)^2})^{.5}\Biggr)dt} = -kx$$

or

2)$$\frac{dx}{\Biggl(\frac{d(\frac{1}{1-(v/c)^2})^{.5})}{dt}\Biggr)} = -kx$$

After substituting $dx/dt$ for v , I am still having nightmares with solving either differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

No relativistic correction is necessary, as you are trying to calculate displacement in the same frame for which you have the function for velocity.

A few notes:

- Check your integration. $\int_{t_0}^{t_f} -kx dt \ne e^{-kt}$
- an $x$-dependent velocity would make for a very strange rocket.
- If you want to convert to a different frame, you do need to do a
  relativistic correction, and yes, the calculus can get tedious. See [this text lecture](https://opentextbc.ca/universityphysicsv3openstax/chapter/relativistic-velocity-transformation/).

Comment: I dont have room in this comment box to explain but I think you misunderstood. The integration is correct./ See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7Bdx%7D%7Bdt%7D+%3D+-kx

Comment: As for the strangeness of the rocket, it is a relativistic variant of Zeno's paradox and simply a story to illustrate the kinematics.

Comment: and yes there are two frames of reference, the observer and the spaceship so I would expect a relativistic correction is needed.

Comment: Consider the extreme case: a beam of light is traveling towards you. Suppose you are in the unprime frame and the beam of light is in the prime frame. For displacement $s$, $\dot s(t) = c$. $s(t) = c \Delta t$. But for light, $1/\gamma = 0$ so $\dot s'(t)$ is undefined and $s'(t) = 0$.